# polymorphic nested form active_admin rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations, activeadmin, polymorphic-associations

I've looked for many solutions on the web and I can't seem to find my answer.

I have a polymorphic association for a table links that it linked to many other tables.

Here is my models a bit simplified:

**links.rb**

```
class Links < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :linkable, polymorphic: true
end
```

**events.rb**

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :links, as: :linkable
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :links
end
```

here is the admin form

**events.rb**

```
ActiveAdmin.register Event do
    form do |f|
        f.has_many :links do |link_f|
            link_f.inputs "links" do
                link_f.input :url
            end
        end
    f.actions
    end

end
```

Here's what in my schema.rb

```
create_table "links", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "url"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "linkable_id"
    t.string   "linkable_type"
end
```

It throws me that error: **uninitialized constant Event::Link**

I can't seem to find the problem and it is driving me nuts...

It seems like a relation is missing or something but I can't find it.

Thanks a lot for every one that can help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is in the way you named your models. Models are always declared as singular entities, not plural.

You should:

1. Rename `links.rb` to `link.rb`
2. Rename `events.rb` to `event.rb`
3. Rename `class Links < ActiveRecord::Base` to `class Link < ActiveRecord::Base`

and see if that helps.

Comment: Perfect! I think I was so much into my code that I couldn't see it. Turned out that I made a mistake writing the events.rb, it was singular but links wasn't, now it works. Thanks a lot.